# "SAT" probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem: There are 3 Republicans and 2 Democrats on a Senate committee. if a 3-person subcommittee is to be formed from this committee, what is the probability of selecting 2 Republicans and 1 democrat?

My attempt: I think the probability would be 3/10 times 2/10 = 6/100. 3= 3 nCr 2; 2= 2nCr1. 10= 5 nCr 2.

How am I wrong?
answer =6/10

Comment: How many three-person subcommittees are there? How many are there with exactly $2$ Republicans?

Comment: This line is impenetrable: "3/10 times 2/10 = 6/100. 3= 3 nCr 2; 2= 2nCr1. 10= 5 nCr 2." What doy you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom 53$ ways to select a subcommittee of $3$ people.

There are $\binom 32$ ways of selecting two republicans, and $\binom 21$ ways of selecting one democrat. So, there are $\binom 32 \times \binom 21$ ways of selecting two republicans, and then one democrat.

All together, we conclude that the probability of forming the committee described is
$$
\frac{\binom 32 \times \binom 21}{\binom 53} = \frac{3 \times 2}{10} = \frac 6{10}
$$

Answer (score 0):

there are $3$ ways to select the republican not in the group and $2$ ways to select the democrat not in the group. Thus there are $6$ suitable groups.

on the other hand there are $\binom{5}{3}=\binom{5}{2}=\frac{5\cdot4}{2}=10$ groups total

so the probability is $\frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{5}=60\%$